# Filtering a protected column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I'm trying to filter a protected column in a spreadsheet that I shared with other users.

But I it looks like I can protect it or filter it with the other user but not both.

In Excel I can do it without a problem. Do I have any option to do so?

Comment: What's a "lock column"?

Comment: lock column for editing by other user. It can be bunch of cells as well if you like..

Comment: That is usually called "protected", not "locked". I edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

At this time, on Google Sheets

- owner and users **with** permissions to edit a **protected range**

  - are allowed

    - to filter it.
    - to edit saved filters.
- users **without** permissions to edit a **protected range**

  - **are not** allowed

    - to filter the protected range.
    - to edit view filters created by others.
  - are allowed

    - to create temporary and to save view filters
    - to edit own saved view filters.

The above behaviour is by-design. If you want that it be changed, submit a feature request through the Help menu > Report a problem

An alternative is to add an auxiliary sheet to include the data from the protected range by using an array like the following:

```
={Sheet1!A:B}
```

This way the original data is kept secure while allowing users without permission to edit the protected range with edit access to filter views on the auxiliary sheet created by others.

References

- [Protect, hide and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en)
- [Sort and filter your data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

If a column of a spreadsheet is protected from a user (i.e., that user does not have edit rights to the column), then the user cannot use Filter command from the menu.  The command will even be greyed out when the cursor is in that column; it won't be greyed out elsewhere but an attempt to filter will still be blocked if it would affect a protected range.

The reason is that applying a filter is considered editing: the appearance of the spreadsheet is changed for *everyone*.

Solution: the users who are unable to apply a filter to the document should use a *filter view*, as described in [Filters vs. filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en).